# Adding constraint to UILabel Programatically with NSLayout

Tags: swift, uilabel, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to add a UILabel to my ViewController and use NSLayout to constrain it. However the UILabel doesn't even appear in my view when I try to use NSLayout. Anyone know a solution?

```
      excersice1label = UILabel()
      excersice1label.textAlignment = .center
      excersice1label.text = "Excercise 1"
      excersice1label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
      view.addSubview(excersice1label)

      NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        excersice1label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        excersice1label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor ,constant: -110),
        excersice1label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width - 64)
        ])
```

Comment: (1) _Watch the console_. The Xcode console is telling you _exactly_ what the problem is. (2) The word is "Exercise".

Comment: @matt thanks, Yes I already have a different label for called exercise so I named this excersice.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add this line:

```
exercise1label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

According to Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622572-translatesautoresizingmaskintoco):

> If this property’s value is true, the system creates a set of
>   constraints that duplicate the behavior specified by the view’s
>   autoresizing mask. If you want to use Auto Layout to dynamically
>   calculate the size and position of your view, you must set this
>   property to false, and then provide a non ambiguous, nonconflicting
>   set of constraints for the view.